# MYSQL sync tables in 2 different databases with triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers, synchronization

i have 2 MySQL databases:

- test
- prod

And i want to sync 1 table in these databases (admin_tasks)

I want to know if I can do this with triggers without getting stuck in an infinite loop.

I created 3 triggers (one for inserts, one for updates and one for deletes). If I create them only on lets say "prod", then it works fine if I insert/update/delete something on prod, it gets the same result on test.

However, if I create the same triggers on test, and want to update something on any of the databases, I can't, due to , which makes sense. They are updating each other in an infinite loop.

Here are my triggers for "prod" database. They are exactly the same on "test", but with the inverted database names:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_prod_to_test_admin_tasks_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `admin_tasks`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
insert into `test`.`admin_tasks`(id, owner, title, description) 
values (new.id, new.owner, new.title, new.description);
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_prod_to_test_admin_tasks_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `admin_tasks`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  UPDATE `test`.`admin_tasks` 
     SET owner = new.owner,
         title = new.title,
         description = new.description,
     where id = old.id;
END

CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_prod_to_test_admin_tasks_delete` BEFORE DELETE ON `admin_tasks`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DELETE from `test`.`admin_tasks` 
     where id = old.id;
END
```

Can i change something to make this sync happen with triggers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use triggers to make the syncing bidirectional, because it would create an infinite loop, as you have said.

I strongly recommend you don't do it even if you could.

Why would you want to risk changes made in the test database to be replicated in production? That sounds like a high risk of corrupting your production data. The changes should go one way, from production to test, not from test to production.

I wouldn't use the same MySQL instance for testing. If your test creates a costly query, it would compete for resources and slow down the production traffic. You might be thinking you can co-host the test database on the same MySQL instance, but this isn't good for your performance.

It's more common to host the test database on a separate MySQL instance. If you need it to copy data updates automatically, you could use MySQL replication to keep the test instance in sync.

But I've never seen a test environment that needed to get every change from production in real time. It's enough to get a daily snapshot of production. Just make a backup of production and use that backup to restore to the test instance before a test run.

Even that is sometimes not called for. There could be sensitive data about users in the production database, and you should avoid using that for testing. Also, the production database may be significantly larger than you need for testing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It is only this single table that i want to keep in sync between prod and test, since i want to use it's data in both environments. Other than this, everything you've said, I strongly agree with you and this is the way I'm going. I just wanted a bidirectional replication between these two tables without using something more complicated than a trigger, because these are the only tables i need to keep in sync. But, since i can't, I may have to come up with a different plan. Thanks!